# Observable.fromCallable() does not Return data from Arraylist in Android using RXJava

Tags: android, arraylist, rx-java

I am trying to use RXjava to get data from an Arraylist in Android

```
public ArrayList<String> SelecIDValueGetterObservable(Context mContext) {
        ArrayList<String> SelectedIds = new ArrayList<>();
        CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        mCompositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromCallable(() -> SelecetIDValuegetter(mContext))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               // .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ArrayList<String> IdObsList) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                "size " + IdObsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        
                            for (int i = 0; i < IdObsList.size(); i++) {
                                SelectedIds.add(IdObsList.get(i));
                            }
                      
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        // mCompositeDisposable.dispose();
                    }
                })
        );
        return SelectedIds;
    }
```

the `SelecetIDValuegetter(mContext)` is Like this

```
    public ArrayList<String> SelecetIDValuegetter(Context mContext) {
            ArrayList<String> SelectedIds = new ArrayList<>();
             SelectedIds .add("A");
             SelectedIds .add("B");
             SelectedIds .add("C");
            SelectedIds .add("D");
            return SelectedIds ;
        }
```

If   SelecetIDValuegetter emits data normally, hwoever It deosnot work In Rxjava, how can we do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Observable`, you should not return `list` directly as `Observable` is `async`, instead return `Observable` and subscribe to receive the data

```
public Observable<List<String>> SelecIDValueGetterObservable(Context mContext) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> SelecetIDValuegetter(mContext));     
}
//at receiver end
SelecIDValueGetterObservable(this)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(IdObsList -> {
                    //ypu will get the list here
            });
```

On a side note, Not sure about your need for using `Observable` in between `SelecetIDValuegetter`, you can directly return the `list` instead of using an `Observable` as you are not doing heavy work in method `SelecetIDValuegetter` AFAIK.

Comment: can you explain the `.subscribe(` part a bit,I am new to Rxjava Trying to learn about it.how do we use it with CompositeDisposable?